# li elements to occupy the whole width of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a simple mobile site. In one part of it, I have an unordered list.

```
<ul id="list" class="sortable"></ul>
```

which follows these css rules:

```
.sortable,li {
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
    li {

        list-style: none;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        background: #F6F6F6;
        color: #1C94C4;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        height: 22px;
    }
    li.sortable-placeholder {
        border: 1px dashed #CCC;
        background: none;
    }
```

The li elements are dynamically added via javaScript. The problem I have is that the output is not covering the whole width of the screen. There is a lot of space left at the starting, as evident in the screenshot:

[image]

What's wrong? What should I do? How do I fix this?

Comment: Tip: open your browser's inspector, and you'll see what's going on. That's the very first step when debugging your markup and styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Make the ul containing that li to have no margin or padding.

`#list { margin:0; padding:0; }`

<strike>You can also try adding a `display:block` to your `li` css.</strike>

Edit (thanks elclanrs): UL and LI are both block level elements. It's just your margin/padding on the ul which is to blame.

Answer (score 1):

```
ul#list{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;   
}
```

[FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YtDU4/3/)